# match multiple substrings using findall from re library

Tags: python, string, substring, python-re

I have a large array that contains strings with the following format in Python

```
some_array = ['MATH_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER MORE_TEXT  SOME_VALUE',
'SCIENCE_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER MORE_TEXT  SOME_VALUE',
'ART_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER MORE_TEXT  SOME_VALUE]
```

I just need to extract the substrings that start with MATH, SCIENCE and ART. So what I'm currently using

```
  my_str = re.findall('MATH_.*? ', some_array )

    if len(my_str) > 0:
        print(my_str)

    my_str = re.findall('SCIENCE_.*? ', some_array )

    if len(my_str) !=0:
        print(my_str)

    my_str = re.findall('ART_.*? ', some_array )

    if len(my_str) > 0:
        print(my_str)
```

It seems to work, but I was wondering if the findall function can look for more than one substring  in the same line or maybe there is a cleaner way of doing it with another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also match optional non whitespace characters after one of the alternations, start with a word boundary to prevent a partial word match and match the trailing single space:

`\b(?:MATH|SCIENCE|ART)_\S*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/alEKRf/1)

Or if only word characters `\w`:

`\b(?:MATH|SCIENCE|ART)_\w*`

Example

```
import re

some_array = ['MATH_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER MORE_TEXT  SOME_VALUE',
              'SCIENCE_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER MORE_TEXT  SOME_VALUE',
              'ART_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER MORE_TEXT  SOME_VALUE']

pattern = re.compile(r"\b(?:MATH|SCIENCE|ART)_\S* ")
for s in some_array:
    print(pattern.findall(s))
```

Output

```
['MATH_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER ']
['SCIENCE_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER ']
['ART_SOME_TEXT_AND_NUMBER ']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|` to match multiple different strings in a regular expression.

```py
re.findall('(?:MATH|SCIENCE|ART)_.*? ', ...)
```

You could also use `str.startswith` along with a list comprehension.

```py
res = [x for x in some_array if any(x.startswith(prefix) 
          for prefix in ('MATH', 'SCIENCE', 'ART'))]
```